# How do I reference an Excel sheet name in an Excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I reference an Excel sheet name in an Excel formula?

Comment: What do you mean?   Why have you not accepted or commented on any of the answers?  Are they providing the information you want?  If not, what’s the problem?

Answer (score 26):

#### How do I reference an excel sheet name in an excel formula?

Use the following syntax:

```
SheetName!CellAddress
```

Notes:

- The worksheet name comes before the cell address, followed by an exclamation mark `!`.
- If the worksheet name includes spaces, enclose it in single quotation marks `'`.

Example:

```
'Sheet Name with spaces'!CellAddress
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Referencing cells outside the worksheet](http://www.officetooltips.com/excel/tips/referencing_cells_outside_the_worksheet.html)

Comment: What about the case where `CellAddress` uses some function such as `Offset/Index/Indirect/...` ?

Answer (score 7):

If your *sheetname* includes spaces, you must use single quotes:

```
='My Sheet'!B3
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",A1)))

Comment: That formula give you the name of the worksheet

Comment: I think this was what the OP was actually after. The title seems very clear to me. I needed a way of a sheet cell to respond to the sheet name. This does the trick. Many thanks Drew

Answer (score 1):

You simply use

```
=Sheet2!C25
```

In this case, I'm referencing Sheet2, cell C25

If I had named the sheet something like DataSheet, I would use

```
=DataSheet!A1
```

The above would access the A1 cell of DataSheet

So, if my DataSheet A1 had the value 5, and my Sheet1 A1 had the value 15 , then on my ResultsWorkSheet I could have

```
=DataSheet!A1 + Sheet1!A1
```

or

```
=SUM(DataSheet!A1,Sheet1!A1)
```